# Объединение json элементов

Tags: php

Получаю с БД данные в следующем виде

```
[{"category":"Приемы специалистов","price":["1002","1003","637"]},{"category":"Инструментальные методы исследования","price":["990"]},{"category":"Лабораторные исследования","price":["975","685","686","1006","1007","678","1011"]},{"category":"Процедуры","price":["971"]}] 

[{"category":"Приемы специалистов","price":["51","50"]},{"category":"Инструментальные методы исследований","price":["466","267"]},{"category":"Лабораторные исследования","price":["844","689","1023","1024","725","678"]},{"category":"Процедуры","price":["630"]}]
```

Как правильно объеденить такого рода строки с ожидаемым результатом:

```
[{"category":"Приемы специалистов","price":["1002","1003","637","51","50"]},{"category":"Инструментальные методы исследования","price":["990","466","267"]},{"category":"Лабораторные исследования","price":["975","685","686","1006","1007","678","1011","844","689","1023","1024","725","678"]},{"category":"Процедуры","price":["971","630"]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ниже один из вариантов решения:

```
<?php
$json1 = '[{"category":"Приемы специалистов","price":["1002","1003","637"]},{"category":"Инструментальные методы исследования","price":["990"]},{"category":"Лабораторные исследования","price":["975","685","686","1006","1007","678","1011"]},{"category":"Процедуры","price":["971"]}]'; 

$json2 = '[{"category":"Приемы специалистов","price":["51","50"]},{"category":"Инструментальные методы исследований","price":["466","267"]},{"category":"Лабораторные исследования","price":["844","689","1023","1024","725","678"]},{"category":"Процедуры","price":["630"]}]' ;

# convert first JSON string to PHP array
$result = json_decode($json1, true);

#var_dump($result);

# loop trough second JSON
foreach (json_decode($json2, true) as $cat) {
    foreach ($result as &$res_cat) {
        $added = false;
        if ($cat['category'] == $res_cat['category']) {
            # in case category already exists - merge prices
            $res_cat['price'] = array_merge($res_cat['price'], $cat['price']);
            $added = true;
            break;
        }
    }   
    if (!$added) {
        # add category that have not merged before
        array_push($result, $cat);
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Вы можете проверить и/или изменить код здесь [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=3ed5d63dce2ead9907602e2ee896f7ff&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: В вашей реализации "category" в финальном массиве дублируется.

Comment: Вы правы, проблема решена добавлением break; в цикл